# Firebase with React Compile Error Identifier Exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

First, thanks for reading this.

I'm following a tutorial, step by step, about implementing firebase with react.  My code matches exactly the tutorial, which is working on the tutorial author's video.  Also, a similar function called signup.js is structured the exact same way and is not throwing compiler errors.  I actually used the signup.js file to structure the login.js file, with only updates to reflect the distinct file.

Is this a bug in the compiler?
Or is something in my code actually causing this?

I'll buy the person who solves it a pizza.   Thanks!

Compiler Error

```
    Failed to compile.
    ./src/pages/Login.js
  Line 6:5:  Parsing error: Identifier 'login' has already been declared

  4 | import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
  5 | 
> 6 | var login(props) {
    |     ^
  7 |   const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
  8 |   const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

I have two relevant files, auth.js and login.js.

auth.js is:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

export const signup = async ({ firstName, lastName, email, password }) => {
  const resp = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  const user = resp.user;
  await user.updateProfile({ displayName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`});
  return user;}


export const logout = () => {
  return firebase.auth().signOut();
};

export const login =  async ({ email, password }) => {
  const resp = await firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  return resp.user;
};
```

and login.js is:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { login } from '../firebase/auth';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function login(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    let User;
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      User = await signup(data);
      reset();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    if (User) {
      props.history.push(`/profile/${User.uid}`);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const formClassName = `ui form ${isLoading ? 'loading' : ''}`;

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="ui card login-card">
        <div className="content">
          <form className={formClassName} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="field">
              <label>
                Email
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  ref={register}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>
                Password
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  ref={register}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="field actions">
              <button className="ui primary button login" type="submit">
                Login
              </button>
              or
              <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

working signup.js file to show you how similar they are:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { signup } from '../firebase/auth';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function Signup(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    let newUser;
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      newUser = await signup(data);
      reset();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    if (newUser) {
      props.history.push(`/profile/${newUser.uid}`);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  const formClassName = `ui form ${isLoading ? 'loading' : ''}`;

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="ui card login-card">
        <div className="content">
          <form className={formClassName} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="two fields">
              <div className="field" >
                <label>
                  First Name
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    ref={register}
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="field">
                <label>
                  Last Name
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    ref={register}
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>
                Email
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  ref={register}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>
                Password
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  ref={register}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="field actions">
            <button className="ui primary button login" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </button>
            or
            <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your login.js file:

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { login } from '../firebase/auth';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function login(props) {
...
```

You're importing a function called login on line 2, and then you're trying to declare another function called login on line 5. You'll have to rename the import or rename the function.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this.  I have seen this solution offered before in my googlez, but I can't explain why it works in signup.js and not login.js.  They are doing the same thing, importing that function and and then passing props in a function.  Do you have any thought on that?  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: If you're referring to `Signup` the import, and `signup`, the function, it's because one is capitalized and the other isn't. JavaScript identifiers are case-sensitive.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  I think this was complicated by the fact that I needed to restart node.js.  This solution did not work on previous attempts, but this time, it worked just fine!  Send me your details and I'll send a pizza!

Comment: Thanks @PappyCode ! No pizza required—I'm just glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

dude, you declare a variable and a function with the same name.. you owe me a pizza :P

Comment: Thank you @zergski  You were right, but I had to restart everything to get the correct result.